# How to check elements has same id in element parent scrolled to top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i had:

```
<ul>
  <li class="test"><h1>One</h1><a id="stt">abc</a></li>
  <li class="test"><h1>Two</h1><a id="stt">abc 2</a></li>
  <li class="test"><h1>Three</h1><a id="stt">abc 3</a></li>
  <li class="test"><h1>Four</h1><a id="stt">abc 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now, i want when each test class scrolled to top, change text of stt id to viewed.
How can i do that?
I trying to use:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
           var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
            for (var i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                //i can't change text off stt id in here
            }
        });
```

Comment: IDs MUST be unique on document context, your HTML markup is not valid!

Comment: So, How should i do??

Comment: Use class intead. Now you should tell exactly what you are looking for, i don'treally get it